# Python VTK clip/cut collection of planes with bounding box

Tags: python, intersection, vtk, plane

**Action**

To bound/clip/cut a collection of (infinite) planes (either represented by normal and point or by plane equation) to a bounding box/volume.

**Attempt**

```
# `planes_data` (a Pandas dataframe containing centroid and normal vector for each plane)

planes = vtk.vtkPlaneCollection()

for centroid, normal in zip(planes_data.centroid.tolist(), planes_data.normal_vector.tolist()):
    plane=vtk.vtkPlane()
    plane.SetOrigin(centroid[0],centroid[1],centroid[2])
    plane.SetNormal(normal[0],normal[1],normal[2])
    planes.AddItem(plane)

# `bounds` is an array (2*3) containing min_XYZ and max_XYZ 

bounding_box = vtk.vtkPlanesIntersection()
bounding_box.SetBounds(bounds[0,0],bounds[1,0],bounds[0,1],bounds[1,1],bounds[0,1],bounds[1,1])

clipper = vtk.vtkClipPolyData()
clipper.SetInputConnection(planes_vtk)
clipper.SetClipFunction(bounding_box)
clipper.GenerateClippedOutputOn()

# but apparently clipper requires different InputConnection
```

**Problem**

I think the functionality might be in Python VTK, however due to only being documented with examples (https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/) I cannot figure out how to do this correctly.

Comment: All C++ methods are wrapped in python, so the C++ documentation is valid.

Comment: https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/

Comment: I see, thanks, i'll try figuring it out with those docs!